# Removing duplicate items from an object and getting the sum of a key if there is a duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have an array of objects.

```
var $arr = [
    {'product': 1, 'quantity': 4, 'service': 'AC'},
    {'product': 2, 'quantity': 5, 'service': 'TV'},
    {'product': 1, 'quantity': 3, 'service': 'AC'}
];
```

With this array I need to remove any object where both the 'product' and 'service' keys match. The other thing I need to do is if there is a match between two or more objects, take the 'quantity' value of each and calculate the sum.

I've been using lodash to try and cheive this. Although I feel I'm not too far off finding a solution I can't quite seem to nail the last part of my problem and summing the 'quantity' values together if there is a match.

```
console.log(_.uniqBy($arr, function(v) {
    return v.product === 1;
}));
```

Is this possible at all or do I need to rethink my approach to this issue. Also, I'm chastised by the fact I cannot make use of ES6 which is a shame.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you need `_.mergeWith`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#groupBy) to collect object with the same product and service values to array, then merge each array to one using [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#mergeWith).

The example uses ES6 arrow functions, and array spread:

```js
var $arr = [{"product":1,"quantity":4,"service":"AC"},{"product":2,"quantity":5,"service":"TV"},{"product":1,"quantity":3,"service":"AC"}];

var result = _($arr)
  // group the object by product and service
  .groupBy(({ product, service }) => product + service)
   // merge each group, and if the key is quantity add the numbers
  .map((g) => _.mergeWith(...g, (o, s, k) => k === 'quantity' ? o + s : o))
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```